# How do I import a file type .1.tar.gz into Python?

Tags: python

I am attempting to complete a computational project were I can duplicate sentiment analysis, and find a correlation to parts of speech usage in a data set saved in a tar.gz file. The file is currently saved in my user directory on my University server. Access to the directory is not a problem. The problem that I have is importing the file into Python so that I may run the Counter script. I am very new to the NTLK platform. Can someone please explain how to overcome this obstacle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a gzipped tar file in Python, you can use the [tarfile module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html):

```
import tarfile
tfile = tarfile.open("myfile.tar.gz", "r:gz")
# do stuff
tfile.close()
```

or (on Python 2.7 and up):

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open("myfile.tar.gz", "r:gz") as tfile:
    # do stuff; file will automatically be closed when exiting the with block
```

Answer (score 1):

[`tar`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar) is an archiving tool. You're file is a gzipped tar archive. You'll have to unpack that file:

```
tar -xvzf file.1.tar.gz
```

After which you can easily manipulate the unpacked files in python with regular file operations. You can also use certain python modules for unpacking the archive but I don't see any extra value in that.